# Why my browser fingerprints are not same?

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs

Why my browser fingerprint not same as on http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs ?

I tested browser on http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs/ and i get browser fingerprint = `3156608387`

Then i load script from this link (link from valve.github.io)

```
https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintJS/zipball/master
```

Then upload all code on my server, when i tested i get this data

```
Your browser fingerprint with default settings (canvas, screen resolutin, activeX disabled)

427527

Your browser fingerprint with canvas enabled is:

3587375811

Your browser fingerprint with ie_activex enabled is:

427527

Your browser fingerprint with screen_resolution enabled is:

3239047655
```

I want to know why my browser fingerprint difference from http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs/ .

Answer (score 1):

because the value calculate by various setting, if some setting change, the value changed